# Gulp.js conventions for tasks names

Tags: javascript, coding-style, gulp, naming-conventions, convention

Are there any conventions for writing Gulpfiles, namespacing the tasks, structuring the config file etc?

Maybe there are some basic common-sense things that can be taken from Grunt world?

How do you deal with structuring the Gulpfile as if you were to quit your job and the next JS developer would come and intuitively understand how to build the project?

Comment: http://drewbarontini.com/articles/building-a-better-gulpfile/

Comment: npm module that scaffolds the Gulpfile https://github.com/drewbarontini/noise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we finished up with grouping the names by phase, nesting subtasks under the names of the main phases.

Essentially we used strategy to copy conventions from build libraries of other languages (e.g. gradle) that were already in place, so build commands for all parts of our process would be the same and everybody could figure out what to

This resulted in:

```
build
...
build:compile
build:compile:less
...
test
test:unit
...
test:e2e
...
verify
...
release
release:copy
release:copy:fonts
```