# Gulp error missing script: build in MVC project

Tags: visual-studio, npm, gulp

I have given a project which works ok on other PCs but on mine it doesnt work.
When I hit build, it reports in node logs `error missing script: build`

Steps that I've done
installed nodejs
installed gulp globally and locally (inside of mvc project)

*Warning: I have different versions of nodejs and gulp  then it specified in solution.

here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "css": "gulp"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.9.1",
    "npm": "3.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

so when I hit command `npm run gulp` it says that gulp script doesnt found - expected.
but when I hit `npm run css` Im gettin an error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'css'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.1
3 info using node@v13.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'precss', 'css', 'postcss' ]
5 info lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~precss: tiptimes@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~css: tiptimes@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~css: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~css: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Work\tiptimes\MvcApplication\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Program Files\ConEmu;C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Seq\;C:\Program Files\Seq\Client\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\Stefan Cvetkovic\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Stefan Cvetkovic\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\;C:\Users\Stefan Cvetkovic\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Stefan Cvetkovic\.dotnet\tools
9 verbose lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~css: CWD: C:\Work\tiptimes\MvcApplication
10 silly lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~css: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gulp' ]
11 silly lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~css: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~css: Failed to exec css script
13 verbose stack Error: tiptimes@1.0.0 css: `gulp`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:219:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:219:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1027:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:285:5)
14 verbose pkgid tiptimes@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Work\tiptimes\MvcApplication
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "css"
18 verbose node v13.3.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tiptimes@1.0.0 css: `gulp`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tiptimes@1.0.0 css script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here are my files in the root of MVCApp
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZtMX.png

Im using vs2017
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since it works on other PC, double check their nodejs version and make sur it matches yours.

Also, you either want to run gulp directly (`gulp yourGulpTask`) or add node script within package.json and run them with npm. Ex (add scripts node in your package.json file):

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "watch": "gulp watch",
  },
```

With the previous scripts declaration, if the the gulp task **build**, **test** and **watch** are define within the gulp.js file, you could run the following :

```
npm run build
npm run test
npm run watch
```

When gulp is ran without arguments, it is trying to run the **default** task. In your case, the css script is calling gulp without argument, therefore calling the default gulp task([ 'precss', 'css', 'postcss' ]).

To debug, make sure you can run these gulp-tasks independently

```
gulp precss
gulp css
gulp postcss
```

It feels like your **precss** works fine. Your **css** task is bugging and we never get to **postcss**.

The meaningfull error on your log is this one :

```
verbose lifecycle tiptimes@1.0.0~css: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
```

Most likey confirming the nodejs version issue :: [npm run test - unsafe-perm in lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115884/npm-run-test-unsafe-perm-in-lifecycle/65268025)

On a quick note, running `npm run gulp` would be weird. Should always give meaningfull name to your scripts... [Gulp.js conventions for tasks names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784831/gulp-js-conventions-for-tasks-names)